# Migrate GitHub Organization to Enterprise Cloud

Tags: github, single-sign-on, github-actions, github-enterprise

Seeking input from anyone who has done this before.

---

We need to create additional organizations in GitHub that will be accessible to different groups of users so we moved to the Enterprise Cloud implementation. Our single Org will be moved into the Enterprise to absorb the seats into our Enterprise licenses.

We are using SAML SSO on our current org. I would like to setup a separate IdP definition for the Enterprise SSO configuration to start with and migrate the org users to the enterprise at a later time. ***Will this work as described?***

I realize there may be some action innersource issues for private repos. But I think those just need to be changed to Internal.

If you have performed a similar migration, did you run into any unexpected issues? Do you have any tips to avoid any nasty hiccups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from their support groups is no, this will not work.

> "configuring SSO at the Enterprise will overwrite SSO for all organizations under it."